# How to reference data from vue,js pug template?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, pug

Basically I am trying to make a permalink from an event name. When I get the value from the event name using v-model it works but how do I put the converted permalink back in another input box in pug?

This works:

`"P {{message}}",textarea(rows="2") {{message}}`

but when i try the following:

`input(value="{{message}}"),input(value={{message}}),input(value=#{{message}}),input(value=@{{message}}),input(value=#{message})`

Pug does not render it & shows an indent error.
My question is how do I bind or reference data from Vue in input values ?

Pug template:

```
.col-md-12(style="padding:0px;")
    .col-md-2.labelcont
        label.labeltext Event Name&nbsp;: 
    .col-md-10
        input(
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Event Name"
          v-model="eventname"
        )
.col-md-12(style="padding:0px;")
    .col-md-2.labelcont
        label.labeltext Permalink&nbsp;: 
    .col-md-10
        textarea(
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Event Permalink"
        ) {{eventpermalink}}
```

Vue.js code:

```
var basicinfo = new Vue({

    el: '#basic',
    data: {
      eventname: '',
      eventpermalink: '',
    }
  })

  basicinfo.$watch('eventname', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    basicinfo.eventpermalink = basicinfo.eventname.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g,'').replace(/ +/g,'-').toLowerCase();
  })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `v-bind` directive. This way, you can bind any HTML element's attribute to a value whether it's calculated or a reference to your props or data.

In your case, it would be something like this:

```
input(type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Event Name" 
     v-model="eventname" v-bind:value="YOUR-DATA-OR-WHATEVER")
```

Look the official documentation for further reading:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html